# Python Tuple Operations

Tags: python, tuples

```
[('1950', '6.5', '6.4', '6.3', '5.8', '5.5', '5.4', '5.0', '4.5', '4.4', '4.2',
'4.2', '4.3', ' \n')]
```

How can I sum up the values from position [1] to [12]?

Comment: note that the solutions mention your_list[0] to reference the tuple that is the first elements of your list (I'm not sure if this was intended or not)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to float and sum using a list comprehension:

```
sum(float(x) for x in my_list[0][1:13])
```

*edit*: eeks, range was wrong. edited per comments.

Comment: careful, this one only sums from position 1 to 11!

Answer (score 2):

```
L=[('1950', '6.5', '6.4', '6.3', '5.8', '5.5', '5.4', '5.0', '4.5', '4.4', '4.2', '4.2', '4.3', ' \n')]
sum(map(float,L[0][1:13]))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid creating an extra temporary list, you can use islice

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> L=[('1950', '6.5', '6.4', '6.3', '5.8', '5.5', '5.4', '5.0', '4.5', '4.4', '4.2', '4.2', '4.3', ' \n')]
>>> sum(map(float,islice(L[0],1,13)))
62.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use a lambda and `reduce`.

```
lst = [('1950', '6.5', '6.4', '6.3', '5.8', '5.5', '5.4', '5.0', '4.5', '4.4', '4.2', '4.2', '4.3', ' \n')]

lst_sum = reduce(lambda x, y : float(x) + float(y), lst[0][1:12])
```

Comment: don't use `sum` as a variable name as it clashes with the builtin function `sum` - which coincidentally does the same job as the reduce+lambda. I think the OP expects the items to be added as floats, not as strings